# Magento custom price.phtml on product view page

Tags: magento

I want to set-up a custom product_price_page.phtml on my magento website that will only get called on the product view page. I'm completely lost at how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If want direct.....

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/custom-price.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

See in class

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product function  getPriceHtml();
```

Here you will change price.phtml

other location is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`